# Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' using Jmeter

Tags: sql-server, apache, jdbc, jmeter, sql-server-2016

I have set up all my thread groups,jdbc config connection and jdbc request correctly along with all the required jar files in the same folder where apache jmeter is installed but I am not sure why I keep getting the below response in the View Results Tree when I try running a simple SQL command. I have googled so much on internet but I couldn't find any resolution for this error. Could somebody who has JMeter expertise help me in solving this problem. Thank you so much in advance.

**Error :-**

```
 Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' for connect URL ':jdbc:sqlserver://SDGRD-20\SQL2016:59954;databaseName=AIRProject'
```

**JDBC Connection Config:-**

```
Database URL: :jdbc:sqlserver://ABC\SQL2016:59954;databaseName=Mydatabasename
JDBC Driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

[image]

Comment: MS SQL Server JDBC Jar file present in the correct location?

Comment: yes both sqljdbc and sqljdbc4 executable jar files are present in apache-jmeter-3.2\lib folder.

Comment: Try removing the sqljdbc file: There might be a difference in the instantiation there which could cause an issue.

Comment: still the same.. i closed and reopened jmeter.

Comment: Ok. Interesting. The DB URL starts with a `:`.  Typo or unhandy log output?

Comment: Let me add the screenshot of my jdbc conn config

Comment: Remove the leading semicolon and test again

Comment: I am getting the new error now...

Comment: Response message: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.

Comment: That is better :). So the issue was the ':'. You can download other jars from MS but only use one at the time to prevent the incorrect one from loading and thus persisting the error.

Comment: Finally it ran green!! :) Thank you so much for the help...  a single colon killed me till now....deleted all unnecessary jar files except sqljdbc4 then closed and reopened jmeter and it worked like a charm..

Comment: No problem. Always fun when you have two possible causes at the same time (typo and several jar files in this case).

Comment: Need one more help...I am trying to call stored procs by passing parameters but I would like to pass 10 different values as parameters.. Any thoughts how can i do this..

Comment: Never done that, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove extra :

```
 connect URL 'jdbc:sqlserver://SDGRD-20\SQL2016:59954;databaseName=AIRProject'
```

Comment: That's not the issue I am facing... pls check the screenshot I have added..

Comment: Remove from database url  :